# std::list.end() is not returning "past-the-end" iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

I recently started learning about C++ iterators and pointers, and while messing around with some basic exercises I came upon a situation which I think is really unusual.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <list>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

template<typename ITER>

void print_with_hyphens(ITER begin, ITER end){
    cout << "End: " << *(end) << endl;
    cout << "Begin: " << *begin << endl;

    for(ITER it = begin; it != end; it++){
       cout << *it << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << "Finished" << endl;

}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    list<int> l { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    print_with_hyphens(v.begin(), v.end());
    print_with_hyphens(l.begin(), l.end());
//    print_with_hyphens(a.begin(), a.end());


    return 0;
}
```

And when I run it like this, I get this unusual result:

[Results of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hf1QR.png)

Now, the vector is returning a weird (random, if I'm not mistaken) value, because it's trying to access a value that doesn't exist, hence, "past the end" iterator. 
And it should be the same for lists, yet, the list is returning the value 5. Shouldn't it also return a "past the end" iterator?

Comment: Dereferencing end iterator is an undefined behavior

Comment: `*(end)` is undefined behavior. Unusual results are to be expected.

Comment: But in the "Vector" case I can do:
if(*it == *(end-1)){
   //DO something different only to the last element
}else{
   // do the usual
}

While with lists, it tells me that *(end-1) is not valid, even though the same code works with vectors..

Comment: It's still undefined behavior.  Anything can happen

Comment: Then how could I make sure that the element I'm on is a certain element? In this case, the last one?

Comment: Well if `it != end` then `--end` is the last element of the range.

Comment: Did you mean `if (it == end-1)`?

Comment: @melpomene Yes, and that's what I tried, but it just simply doesn't work for the lists... On the vectors it does, but it crashes on the lists.
Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/6iY4Difn

Comment: Crashes? Or doesn't compile? `end-1` should not compile if `end` is a `std::list::iterator`. Subtraction only works with random access iterators, but `std::list::iterator` is bidirectional. You could do `if (it == std::prev(end))`.

Answer (score 2):

Things such as dereferencing an invalid iterator or accessing an out-of-bounds array index produce [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

This means the C++ standard does not specify what should happen if you do it. Anything might happen, such as a segmentation fault, or getting a random value, depending on things like your standard library implementation and compiler.

Needless to say, programs should not rely on undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "past-the-end" in this context is abstract. It means the iterator is off the end of the logical sequence of elements in the container. It does *not* mean there is some literal bit of data located just after the container in memory that you can access and read.

Because it's "past-the-end" and doesn't refer to any actual element, dereferencing the end iterator is not permitted. By doing so, you get weird behaviours.